# Hadoop Mapreduce example for giving input from hdfs and writing output to excel file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Iam new to Hadoop programming, i found some useful links about mapreduce in Haddop and i can able to process.It was very useful to me and for begineers.

All the examples are shown like giving input from eclipse and output can be seen in output folder in eclipse.

Here i would like to know how to give input from HDFS(i mean instead of giving from eclipse).
and writing the output to some Excel file.

please advice me.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to follow the necessary steps using Java and Excel to make proper manipulation of your information with Hadoop.

- **Upload or add a file to HDFS**

Here you have the typical example on how to make your input:

```
    public void addFile(String source, String dest) throws IOException {     

    // Conf object will read the HDFS configuration parameters
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path("/home/hadoop/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/home/hadoop/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/home/hadoop/hadoop/conf/mapred-site.xml"));

    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);

    // Get the filename out of the file path
    String filename = source.substring(source.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, source.length());

    // Create the destination path including the filename.
    if (dest.charAt(dest.length() - 1) != '/') {
    dest = dest + "/" + filename;
    } else {
    dest = dest + filename;
    }

    // Check if the file already exists
    Path path = new Path(dest);
    if (fileSystem.exists(path)) {
    System.out.println("File " + dest + " already exists");
    return;
    }

    // Create a new file and write data to it.
    FSDataOutputStream out = fileSystem.create(path);
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
    new File(source)));

    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    int numBytes = 0;
    while ((numBytes = in.read(b)) > 0) {
    out.write(b, 0, numBytes);
    }

    // Close all the file descripters
    in.close();
    out.close();
    fileSystem.close();
}
```

Source: [A HDFSClient for Hadoop - Linux Junkies](http://linuxjunkies.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/a-hdfsclient-for-hadoop-using-the-native-java-api-a-tutorial/)

Then follow the instructions on how to visualize the data output:

- [Import the Server Log Data into Excel](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-refine-and-visualize-server-log-data/).

Further information that can be helpful too:

- [Running Hadoop on Ubuntu Linux](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/#download-example-input-data)

Hadoop provides you all necessary tolls you may need with easy integration to optimize your data analysis and manipulation.